# php arithmetic on monetary values

Tags: php, types, floating-point, currency, decimal-point

I have a form which has following inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" maxlength="10" onblur="applyInterest();" />
<input style="width:60px" type="text" name="interest" id="interest" maxlength="6" placeholder="Interest" onkeyup="applyInterest();" />&nbsp;%
<input type="text" name="total_amount" id="total-amount" maxlength="10" readonly />

function applyInterest()
{
    var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById('amount').value);
    var interest = parseInt(document.getElementById('interest').value);
    var int_amount = Math.round((interest/100)*amount);
    document.getElementById('total-amount').value = (amount + int_amount);
}
```

- Inputs may or may not have decimal points (1000, 1000.57) (if they has decimal point, it is up to two decimal points like (10.20, 10.25, 1000.50).
- On keyup of interest(%) input and onblur of amount input i am calculating interest amount and adding it to amount and then filling the total-amount field. The function used is **applyInterest();**
- Then on submit i am again calculating the interest and adding it to amount to make total amount and checks if total amount is same as received in $_POST.

Server side code :

```
$amount = trim($_POST['amount']);
$interest_per = trim($_POST['interest']);
$total_amount = trim($_POST['total_amount']);
$error = array();

if ( ! preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/', $amount)) {
    $error[] = 'Invalid amount';
}

if ( ! preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/', $total_amount)) {
    $error[] = 'Invalid total amount';
}

if ( ! empty($interest_per)) {
    if ( ! preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/', $interest_per)) {
        $error[] = 'Invalid interest';
    }
} else {
    $interest_per = 0;
}

if ( empty($error)) {
    $int_amt = round(($interest_per / 100) * $amount);
    $chk_total_amt = $amount + $int_amt;
    if ($chk_total_amt != $total_amount) {
        $error[] = "Interest plus amount is not matching total amount";
    }
}

if ( ! empty($error)) {
    $message = array('status' => 422, 'data' => $error);
    $conn = null;
    echo json_encode($message);
    exit();
}
```

The amount, interest_amount, interest per and total amount is stored as numeric with 2 precision. (Postgresql).

Now my questions are:

- how to do calculations on these inputs which may or may not contain
  decimal point up to two places (i have read somewhere that arithmetic on floating point numbers is tricky)
- How can i calculate above things properly and accurately both client and server side.

JS Fiddle link for client side code demo: https://jsfiddle.net/deepakthakur07/dnyrf6gt/2/

Comment: if the numbers are small enough, you can use integers (100 for 1.00) and only divide by 100 for displaying to the user.  Or don't bother submitting the interest since you should never trust client-side calculations.  Treat the client-side calculation as for only to display for the user's information.  For the input, *100 makes 33, 33.1 and 33.05 all correct integers (3300, 3310, 3305)

Comment: If i have to use numeric(15,2) instead of integer then what is the solution.

Comment: also when i will receive the input in $_POST, do i need to use floatval()

Comment: As advised by Dave S, there is no need to post calculated interest. You can calculate it on the client side, but only for display purposes. The server side calculation can be performed with a money library that provides exact calculations and predictable rounding capabilities, such as [brick/money](https://github.com/brick/money) (disclaimer: I'm the author).